# How do I compute average marginal effect from glm with robust errors?

Tags: r

I am estimating a logit model with glm() and use export_summs(glm_model, robust= TRUE) to have robust standard errors. Next, I want to compute the average marginal effects using the robust standard errors which I failed so far. Do you have any solution to compute margins with robust errors?

Comment: Have you looked at the package `erer`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/erer/erer.pdf